# CSS Clipping Text in Dynamic Header

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get a dynamic header to clip text using the text-overflow:ellipsis, but I can't seem to get everything working that I need.

Have a look at what we've originally implemented here https://dl.orangedox.com/selZdE Notice that the file name extends over the controls, this is what we're trying to fix by using something like the text-overflow css property.

This is what I've tried

```css
.toolbar {
              width: 100%;
              height: 45px;
              background-color: #fff;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
            }
            
            .middle {
              text-align: center;
            }
            
            .left {
                text-align:left;
            }
            
            .right {
                text-align:right;
            }
            
            .border {
                border:thin solid silver;
            }
            
            .clip {
              overflow: hidden;
              white-space: nowrap;
              text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
            
            #float > div {
                width:32%;
                height:100%;
            }
            
            #inline > div {

              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 0;
              overflow: visible;
              margin-top: 3px;

            }
            
            .hide {
                display:none;
            }
            
            .float-right {
                float:right;
            }
            
            .float-left {
                float:left;
            }
```

```html
    <div id='inline' class="toolbar">
        <div class="inline left clip">
            Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line of text.
        </div>
        <div class="inline middle">Middle Stuff</div>
        <div class="inline right">Right Stuff</div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h3>Second Attempt</h3>
    <br>
 
    <div id='float' class="toolbar">
        <div class="border left float-left clip">
            Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line of text.
        </div>
        <div class="border middle float-left">Middle Stuff</div>
        <div class="border right float-right">Right Stuff</div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <hr>
    <strong>without the middle</strong>
    <br>
 
    <div id='float' class="toolbar">
        <div class="border left float-left clip">
            Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line of text.
        </div>
        <div class="border middle float-left hide">Middle Stuff</div>
        <div class="border right float-right">Right Stuff</div>
    </div>
```

Having a look at the attempts I've tried above

1. Positioning is correct and removing the middle or the right section allows for the left section to "grow" HOWEVER the text overflows in the middle area
   (what we've already implemented
2. Left box is now bounded to 33% of the screen allowing for the text overflow to be controlled BUT
3. if the middle box isn't present then the left box doesn't automatically resize to over this available space (since it's explicitly set at 33%)

Any ideas on how to better structure this header with overflowing text & controls like this?

Comment: show what you have tried so far!?!

Comment: sorry it posted before I finished .. all ready now!

Comment: I'm still not fully sure how you'd like the three parts to act... could you use display: inline-block or display: table-cell instead of the text-align and float combos for those three boxes?

Comment: just to clarify I need all the boxes in order from left to right with the middle box in the middle of the screen PLUS the text in the left box must be clipped if it's too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER:  It looks like you'll need to set a width to the left div, without absolute positioning. The other two can really be styled however.  Eventually I arrived there and I believe this is the end result that you're looking for.

```
    #div1
    {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 40%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    #div2 
    {
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      background: yellow;
      top: -20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #div3 
    {

      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      overflow: visible;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrg3uxn7/3/)

Comment: Interesting, haven't actually used box-sizing before, however the real problem (which I may have not explained very well) has to do with having to set the explicit width of the div in order to take advantage of "text-overflow: ellipsis;" when the text size is too large.  Otherwise it overflows into the middle box.

Comment: re-worded the question to clarify what we're trying to achieve

Comment: answer and fiddle updated... really it's that first div's style that matters (without absolute positioning).

Comment: I was hoping to get away from explicitly setting the size of the left had box (#div1 in your case).  But it seems like it's the only solution so I'll mark as answered.  Thanks!